# Error Rendering Control: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, datetimecontrol

I am exploring on trying to create a custom webpart and I am encountering this error:

In my source, I have a table in which a cell will contain SharePoint:DateTimeControl.

However it will

```
<asp:Table ID="interviewerAndApplicants" Visible="False" runat="server" Width="50%">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>    
            Interview Timeslot:  <SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="interviewSlot" runat="server" />
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

The weird thing is, if the `SharePoint:DateTimeControl` is NOT within a table cell, it displays perfectly in the design. However when it is placed within a cell, it will cause the error:

> "Error Rendering Control: Object reference not set to an instance of
>   an object"

in the designer view.

What exactly am I doing wrong/ missed out on doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also try to build the table using plain html tags like

```
    <table><tr><td>
```

...?

Comment: Nope I didn't. It's a school project and we are kinda not allowed to use html tags. Though I don't see how html tags will help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Control's(interviewerAndApplicants) visible property is set to false. Set it to true and then try.